# run Airflow webserver on EC2 CentOS using Systemd: Permission denied

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm using [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) in EC2 CentOS with [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) to manage daemons for starting airflow processes (ie: webserver, worker and scheduler). 
When I run `sudo systemctl start airflow-webserver`

```
: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl enable airflow-webserver
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal sudo[11680]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start airflow-webserver
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[11684]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/airflow: Permission denied
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit airflow-webserver.service entered failed state.
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service failed
```

*airflow-webserver.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

airflow group and user are present:

```
$ less /etc/group
# airflow:x:1001:ec2-user
$less etc/psswd
# ec2-user:x:1000:1000:EC2 Default User:/home/ec2-user:/bin/bash
# tss:x:59:59:Account used by the trousers package to sandbox the tcsd # daemon:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
# airflow:x:1001:1001::/home/airflow:/bin/bash
```

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291335/run-airflow-process-and-airflow-webserver-as-airflow-user) does not help.

Comment: is `/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/airflow` permission bit marked executable?  If you try running it manually as user airflow does it work?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 1001 1001 1259 Oct 29 21:09 .local/bin/airflow` and if I try running `airflow webserve` it works correctly. but get permission denied when I run webserver from systemd daemon

Comment: did you run it as user airflow?  Is the group correct?

Comment: Feel free to add an answer here once you figure it out...